# Is there a way to use href="tel" in CSS?

Tags: html, css, onclick, href, tel

I'm currently making a website using a builder called 'Elementor'. In my footer, I added an icon which I would like to make clickable, so that when you click it on your phone it uses the `href="tel"` function and pops up the number on your dial screen.

However, I can't seem to find a way to do this using CSS, as Elementor only let's me add custom CSS to icons. The number itself below the icon is clickable, but this is done using the following HTML:

`<a href="tel:1-562-867-5309">1-562-867-5309</a>`

Is there any way to do this using CSS?

Comment: Can you wrap the icon inside the anchor tag? ie: `<a href="tel:1-562-867-5309">...icon...</a>` ?

Comment: CSS is not supposed to make call-to-action stuff. You have to put your icon inside of the `<a>` Tag

Comment: Yes, I was able to wrap it and it now works. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1):

CSS won't be able to wrap an anchor around it as it is used for styling elements.

1. Your options would be to somehow get the icon within the  tags that are currently there.
2. Use CSS to style the current  tag using background-image and padding.
3. Use jQuery to wrap it in an anchor.

Comment: I wrapped it and used the href="tel" and it works now. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use [css attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```css
    a[href ^= 'tel:']:before {
        content: '\1F4F1';
    }
```

```html
<a href="tel:1-562-867-5309">1-562-867-5309</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a pseudo-element

```css
a:before {
  content: '\260E';
}

a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="tel:1-562-867-5309">1-562-867-5309</a>
```